# I am trying to echo the string from the server to the client with UDP sockets but it is failing?

Tags: c, sockets

I have made one server and one client communicating through **UDP sockets**. The work that I am trying to do is that **client** will pass a string in the arguments and that string will be send to the **server** using **UDP sockets**. After receiving the string server will again echo(send) the string back to the client.Below are the codes for both:

code for ***echoClient.c*** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    char sendLine[MAXLINE],recvLine[MAXLINE];

    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("echoClient <Ip addr. of the server> <String to be echoed> \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("Error in creating the socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }


    memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr));

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(6565);    // setting up the port
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);  // using the given ip address of the server

    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);

    if((sendto(sockfd,(const char  *)argv[2],strlen(argv[2]), MSG_CONFIRM,(struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr))!=-1))
    {
        printf("data is sent to the server\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("can't send the data to the server\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    int n = recvfrom(sockfd,(char * ) recvLine,MAXLINE,0,(struct sockaddr * )&servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));

    if(n==-1)
    {
        printf("Can't receive the data from the server\n");
        exit(4);
    }

    recvLine[n] = '\0'; // to terminate the received string

    printf("%s\n",recvLine);


    return 0;
}
```

code for ***echoServer.c***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr,clientAddr;
    char sendLine[MAXLINE],recvLine[MAXLINE];

    if(argc!=1)
    {
        printf("echoServer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("Error in creating the socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }


    memset(&servAddr,0,sizeof(servAddr));
    memset(&clientAddr,0,sizeof(clientAddr));


    // filling the details of the server ip and port
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(6565);
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  // using the given ip address of the server

    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr * )&servAddr,sizeof(servAddr))<0)
    {
        printf("Binding of the socket failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Server is Up... Waiting for the client...\n");

    int len;
    int n = recvfrom(sockfd,(char *) recvLine,MAXLINE,MSG_WAITALL,(struct sockaddr * )&clientAddr,&len);

    if(n==-1)
    {
        printf("can't get the message from the client\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    recvLine[n] = '\0';

    printf("Message received from the client is %s\n",recvLine);

    if(sendto(sockfd,(char *) recvLine,n,MSG_CONFIRM,(struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr,len)<0)
    {
        printf("can't send the message to the client\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now the actual problen is that when I am executing the above codes **client** is able to send the string to the **server** but server is unable to send the string back to the client.Server gives the error **can't send the message to the client**.

I am not able to figure out the error which is stopping the server to send the message to the client.Please help me with this.

I am running the **echoClient.c** with the command : 
**./a.out 127.0.0.1 hellofromclientside**

Comment: @AravindVoggu I tried with n+1 but it is not helping. But I think this might not be the problem because n is only telling the length to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server, you overlooked that the argument `len` to `recvfrom()` is a value-result argument, which before the call you have to initialize to the size of the `clientAddr` in order to get this address, so change

```
    int len;
```

to

```
    int len = sizeof clientAddr;
```

Similarly in the client, change

```
    int n = recvfrom(sockfd,(char * ) recvLine,MAXLINE,0,(struct sockaddr * )&servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));
```

to

```
    int len = sizeof servAddr;
    int n = recvfrom(sockfd, recvLine, MAXLINE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, &len);
```